# Joomla 3.7.2 can't send any emails with contact forms

Tags: joomla

I'm at the end of my rope here and I'm here to get some help. I'm going to try and explain it as best as I can.

I have a website running on Joomla 3.7.2 which you can visit here: https://www.meteordesign.nl

For some reason my contact form does not work anymore. Whenever I click 'send' the page reloads but no confirmation or an email being sent.

I have tried the following:

- Switched from PHP mail to SMTP and send a test mail (came in fine).
- Used several other contact form modules and components and even an HTML one which you can find here https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-recaptcha

They all don't work. I have tried disabling my .htaccess file to see if that solved it but to no avail.

You can find the contact form here:
https://www.meteordesign.nl/contact

I don't know if this is important but recently my hosting provider switched to https. Could that be causing it?

I hope I explained it well. If not feel free to ask me more questions, I really need your help fixing this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally figured it out...

The problem was the cache settings on Joomla at *Global configuration > System > System Cache*. I had it on **Progressive** and after setting it to **Conservative** my contact form worked again!

Answer (score 0):

You are likely running into a JavaScript issue. Just tested this and you seem that you have solved it. Please let us know what the issue was so that others can learn from your experience.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me! It was a problem with my cache settings from Joomla. Will update now!